# Facebook Grap Api get video picture not working on some videos

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to get a video thumbnail with Facebook Grap Api. I do this by using an url: https://graph.facebook.com/VIDEO_ID/picture for example: https://graph.facebook.com/10156455627923832/picture.

The problem is that it does not work by some videos, why?
This url: "https://graph.facebook.com/2195811087130850/picture" returns an error message, which is:

> "Unsupported get request. Object with ID '2195811087130850' does not exist, cannot be loaded due to missing permissions, or does not support this operation. Please read the Graph API documentation at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api"

The ID:2195811087130850 does exist and it is shared with everyone.

I don't understand this, What did I do wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your access token have not access to see it. I'm guessing the page have some restrictions on it.

Comment: The profile this is on is a user profile, https://www.facebook.com/PGPraiseTilburg, so you would need to have this user log in to your app and grant it access to their videos first. (That this should not be a user profile, but a page instead, is a different matter. Resp. they seem to have a proper page, https://www.facebook.com/PraiseTilburg/, but set up a fake account to administrate it.)

Comment: Thank you for your responses. So, it must be a page profile, to be able to get the video thumbnail from? Why is it possible this way? Is it also a solution if the user removes the restrictions on some of their videos so I can get the video picture without facebook login on my app?

Comment: No, there is no way to get any access to user content, without the user granting your app permission first. It does not matter whether stuff is public via the UI or not, API is a different thing.

Comment: If an access token is necessary, why am I able to retrieve pictures from some videos like: https://graph.facebook.com/10156455627923832/picture?